# Single API for all social networking websites?

Tags: php, api, social-networking

Is there such a thing as a single API for all social networking websites? I want people to register in my website with Facebook, Google Plus, Twitter, LinkedIn, Myspace and with all the rest websites like that as far as they provide that functionality.

So, is there such a thing, that I can implement in the website(instead of implementing each api individually)- I need only simple registration - just to verify that they are real people. So, I am looking for something, like it is done for sharing with [addthis.com](http://addthis.com), but for registration.

Comment: @andrewsi, pduersteler, halfer, Pranav Kapoor 웃, singles guys could u please tell me why it is considered off-topic? I understand it is not about some error that I get or some code that I need help, but after all it is about programming, isn't it ? And there are bunch of questions out there like this, that actually are being helpfull to other users, just one example that I just ran into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100130/are-there-any-free-api-for-ip-2-location: in 2 years over 8000 views and 8 votes, if it would not be helpful, I guess it would get even that few vote ups. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this hybridauth API service  http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Thanks man, looks like a good thing, but one question, can I use it with cakephp ? or it is for pure php ? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can, you can download module here http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

OpenID offers a way to log in to websites using accounts from their partners
http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/25453698/Gallery

http://openid.net/